# START w3svc [SC] StartService FAILED 1056: An instance of the service is already running

Tags: jenkins

After I build my application on Jenkins,
the output message says my build is success, however I get this error message in the end, and my website can't work...

```
D:\Jenkins\jobs\1.job\workspace>SC \\123.45.12.133 START w3svc 
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

An instance of the service is already running.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have faced it recently, it's annoying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the w3svc(World Wide Web publishing service) can not start by Jenkins.
So you should start it manually by following steps:

1. Open your services in administrative tool
2. Right click w3svc(World Wide Web publishing service) and re-start it.

Or use command line and input `sc start w3svc`

Comment: It's exactly what I need!